# "Slow motion" effect on Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to record a video  with "slow motion" effect on Windows Phone devices? I tried to find some info about this feature but i didn't find anything

Comment: Some incompetent but high-reputation SO users voted to close your question. Anyway.
The short answer to your question – it’s only possible for some use-cases.
Both camera and video codecs support 30 FPS max.

Comment: You can grab frames from the video camera in the real-time (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580743.aspx). So, you can keep up to 1-2 minutes of uncompressed video in RAM (or more, if you’ll implement some cheap way to compress video), you can play that data with any framerate you want, and you can even save the video, however you’ll get no support from the OS, you can’t use the OS-supplied video codecs, and I doubt the system performance is enough to save video in the realtime.

Comment: You can encode video from camera in h264 using the FileSink class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394041(VS.92).aspx). The class is only capable of recording raw stream from the camera. You can’t modify the stream, and save it in the file system. It is possible to play the file with slow motion, but it’s hard, you’ll have to implement custom MediaStreamSource to do that, and override the timestamp value for the frames you feed to the decoder.

Comment: I agree that this shouldn't have been closed. I think the question is really clear and if someone can point to the right direction it would be valuable.

Comment: This question may be better received at http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/